# Writing a decompression mechanism to be used in a Web API MessageHandler

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to write a decompression mechanism for a Web API MessageHandler. However, despite a little research I can't seem to make this work :-(

The problem is reproducible with the following test:

```
[Test]
public void Deflate()
{
    using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var compressionStream = new DeflateStream(outStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
        {
            using (var original = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("original content")))
            {
                original.CopyTo(compressionStream);
            }
        }
        //this passes
        Assert.IsTrue(outStream.Length > 0);

        var compressedStream = outStream;
        var decompressionResultStream = compressedStream.DeflateDecompressor();

        //this fails
        Assert.IsTrue(decompressionResultStream.Length > 0);

        var output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decompressionResultStream.ToArray());
        Assert.AreEqual("original content", output);
    }
}
```

and the following Decompression Handler

```
public static class DecompressionHandlers
{
    public static MemoryStream DeflateDecompressor(this Stream compressedStream)
    {
        var decompressionResultStream = new MemoryStream();
        using (var decompressionStream = new DeflateStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress, true))
        {
            decompressionStream.CopyTo(decompressionResultStream);
            decompressionStream.Flush();
        }
        return decompressionResultStream;
    }

    public static MemoryStream GZipDecompressor(this Stream compressedStream)
    {
        var decompressionResultStream = new MemoryStream();
        using (var decompressionStream = new GzipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress, true))
        {
            decompressionStream.CopyTo(decompressionResultStream);
            decompressionStream.Flush();
        }
        return decompressionResultStream;
    }
}
```

Hopefully, this is a straight ID-ten-T problem and any advice is gratefully received!

That this is to be used in a Web API MessageHandler may well be a red herring but is included for completeness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, try resetting the position of the `compressedStream` before you invoke decompression on it.

```
compressedStream.Position = 0;
var decompressionResultStream = compressedStream.DeflateDecompressor();
```

Note that you seem to be using DeflateStream instead of GZipStream in your GZipDecompressor method.

Comment: Ah,  yep,  I need to support both and didn't stay consistent in the question. I'll edit and also try your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: That nailed it. Thanks!